# How to circle sliding window?

Tags: c++, sliding-window

How do I make a slide with last element and some of firsts. You might not get my question, so I better give you an example.

In this array:
`{1, 2, 5, 4, 3}`
If I try to find the min sum of 3 numbers,  it checks the slides:
`{1, 2, 5}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 4, 3}`
And gives me `8` as result.

But how do I also check `{3, 1, 2}, {4, 3 ,1}`? Like if we imagine the array as circle of numbers.

The code I have now is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int minsum(int arr[], int n, int k)
{
    if (n < k)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    int windowsum = sum;
    for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
    {
        windowsum += arr[i] - arr[i - k];
        sum = std::min(sum, windowsum);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 5,4, 3};
    int k = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::cout << minsum(arr, n, k) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So also check those two extra slides? What is the issue you are having with your attempts at that? For example, you can use indices modulo `n` to implement it quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of "flip overs" or "overflows" can be easily handled with modulo division.

If you have for example 5 elements in your array, then allowed indices are 0,1,2,3,4. So, never greater than 4. And this we can achieve with modulo division, in C++ with the `%` operator. Please see the following example:

```
Modulo division
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
6 % 5 = 1
7 % 5 = 2
8 % 5 = 3
9 % 5 = 4
. . .
```

With that approach, we can "limit" your indices or make them "flip around". The limited index in below table is simply calculated by using the `%`operator.

Please see:

```
Runnning    Limited
Index       Index
0 1 2  -->  0 1 2   
1 2 3  -->  1 2 3   
2 3 4  -->  2 3 4   
3 4 5  -->  3 4 0   
4 5 6  -->  4 0 1
```

Now it is clear how to calculate indices. We start a normal for loop. The beginning index is 0,1,2,3,4, the end index is 2,3,4,5,6 and corrected with `%` --> 2,3,4,0,1. Good. This problem is solved.

Next, if we want to find the minimum of something, we define the variable "minimumWindowSum" and compare it with the resulting sum of the current window "sumOfCurrentWindow". If the current value is smaller then the minimum, we will use it for the new minium. The problem is the initial value of "minimumWindowSum". We must initialize it with something very big, so that even the first "sumOfCurrentWindow" is always and guarnateed lower. For this we simply use the maximum possible data type for this variable.

C++ will help us here with the [limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) library. And here, especially with the [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). If we need for example the maximum integer value, we can write:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

So, now we know the 2 major building blocks for our program.

We can write now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int minsum(int arr[], int n, int k) {
    int minimumWindowSum = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    if (k < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int w = i; w < (i + k); ++w)
                sum += arr[w % n];
            if (sum < minimumWindowSum)
                minimumWindowSum = sum;
        }
    }
    return minimumWindowSum;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
    int k = 3;
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::cout << minsum(arr, n, k) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this is still rater "C-Style". In C++ we do usually not use C-Style arrays for such tasks. A `std::array` or a `std::vector` is nearly always the better choice. It has the additional advantage that those containers "know" their size. And with that, you can write a better program.

One example could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Calculate the minimum sum of a sliding window over a vector
int minSum(const std::vector<int>& data, std::size_t windowLength) {

    // Initialize with maximum possible value. Return this in case of error
    int minimumWindowSum{ std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

    // Sanity check. Basically not necessary
    if (windowLength <= data.size())

        // Calculate the sum for each possible sliding window
        for (std::size_t index{}; index < data.size(); ++index) {

            // This will hold the sum of the current window
            int sumOfCurrentWindow{};

            // Sum up vector elements at sliding window indices
            for (std::size_t slidingWindowIndex{}; slidingWindowIndex < (index + windowLength); ++slidingWindowIndex)
                sumOfCurrentWindow += data[slidingWindowIndex % data.size()];
            // Check for a new minimum
            if (sumOfCurrentWindow < minimumWindowSum)
                minimumWindowSum = sumOfCurrentWindow;
        }
    // And show result
    return minimumWindowSum;
}
int main() {
    std::vector data{ 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
    std::cout << minSum(data, 5) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranges come very handy here. The problem is that many of them, like `repeat(n)`, won't be available in the standard library until C++23. Meanwhile, you can use Eric Niebler's range-v3 library:

- You start from `arr`.
- The pipe operator, `|`, will get one range (e.g. the initial `arr`, or the view resulting from operating on a range), and pass it as an input to the next algorithm.
- `cycle` takes a range and forms an "infinite" view of that range by repeating its elements time and again.
- `sliding(n)` takes a range and forms a view that is a range of subranges of `n` elements, each starting in consecutive positions of the original range.
- `take(n)` takes exactly `n` elements from a given range.
- `transform` takes a range, applies an operation on each element, and generates a view with the result of each operation.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/W78478c94)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace rv3 = ranges::views;

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
    int n{ std::size(arr) };
    fmt::print("size of arr: {}\n", n);
    auto&& threes{ arr
        | rv3::cycle       // [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5...]
        | rv3::sliding(3)  // [[1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 4], [5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]...]
        | rv3::take(n)     // [[1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 4], [5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
    };
    fmt::print("threes: {}\n", threes);
    auto&& sums_of_threes{ threes
        | rv3::transform([](auto&& v) { return ranges::accumulate(v, 0); })
    };
    fmt::print("sums of threes: {}\n", sums_of_threes);
    auto min_of_sums_of_threes{ *ranges::min_element(sums_of_threes) };
    fmt::print("min of sums of threes: {}\n", min_of_sums_of_threes);
}

// Output:
//
//   size of arr: 5
//   threes: [[1, 2, 5], [2, 5, 4], [5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
//   sums of threes: [8, 11, 12, 8, 6]
//   min of sums of threes: 6
```

---

I've separated the creation of the `threes` and the `sums_of_threes` view just for demoing purposes, but you could create `sums_of_threes` directly.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/K1YY8oxdz)